# 3D Objects are not being in their regular shape at distance

Tags: camera, unity-game-engine, rendering, culling

I am working on a game which was developed by some other guy earlier. I am facing a problem that when player(with camera) start running on the road the buildings are not being shown up in their regular shape and as we move forward (more closer to the buildings) they gain their original shapes, and some times the buildings present on either side of the road are not visible by camera ( empty space ) and when we move closer to the building it comes up as visible object suddenly. I think it may be some unity3d setting problem (rendering , camera or quality). May be, it was being done due to increase performance on mobile devices.

can anybody know what may be the issue or how to resolve it.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it's a problem with the available LODs for each building's 3D model.

Basically, 3d games work by having 2-3 different versions of each 3D model, with varying **L**evels **O**f **D**etail. So for example, if you have a house model which uses 500 polygons, you'll probably have another 2 versions (eg 250 polys and 100 polys), which are used depending on the distance between the player and the object. The farther away he is, the simpler the version used will be.

The issue occurs when developers use automatically generated LOD models, which will look distorted or won't appear at all. Unity probably auto generates them, but I'm unsure where you'll find the settings for this in unity. However I've seen 3d models on the unity store offering models with different LODs, so unity probably gives you the option to set your own. The simplest solution would be to increase the distance the LODs change at, while the complicated solution would be to fix custom versions of the 3D models for larger distances, with a lower poly count.

Comment: thanks for the response.Yes, there are LODs used in the game.I am new in unity3d so don't know about them too much.Can you elaborate these LOD's more precisely ? And how can i increase the distance ? sorry for this naive question :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem. This was due to the [LOD (level of details)](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/LevelOfDetail.html) used for objects (buildings) in Unity3d to enhance the performance on the slower device. LOD provides many level of details (of an object) which you can adjust according to your need . In my specific problem the buildings were suddenly appear due to the different (wrong) position for LOD1, i.e. for LOD1 the building was at wrong place but for LOD0 it was at its right place. So when my camera see from the distance it see LOD1 which was at wrong place thence it sees empty space with no building at the expected position. But when camera comes closer it sees LOD0 in which building is at the right position and it seems that buildings are suddenly come or become visible.